# Accessing nested array values in swiftui?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a nested array that I'm working with.

I need to access some values from this nested array.

I can access the Root values but not the nested values with my code.

This my current code:

```
    // MARK: - Root
    struct RootD: Codable {
        let id: Int
        let books: String
        let regs: [SightingsD]
        
    
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case id = "id"
            case serial = "books"
            case regs = "regs"
        }
    }
    
    
    struct SightingsD: Codable, Identifiable {
        public var id: Int
        public var regNo: String
     
    
        
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case id = "id"
            case regNo = "regNo"
    
            }
    }
```

**And I can access the Root stuff like this:**

```
          if let str = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
             
                let data = str.data(using: .utf8)!
                do {
                    if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                    {

                        books = jsonArray["books"] as! String

                        
                    } else {
                        print("bad json")
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }

            }
```

But how can I access stuff like `regNo` ?

Comment: you have the data , then you convert it to string and then to data again ? why ? use it directly as Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `JSONDecoder`

```
guard let data = data else { return }
  do {
       let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(RootD.self, from:data)  
       res.regs.forEach { 
           print($0.regNo)
       }
     
  } catch {
      print(error)
  }
```